# How does this decorator work in python

Tags: python, python-decorators

I had this decorator written by someone else in code and i am not able to get it

```
def mydecorator(a, b):
        def f1(func):
            def new_func(obj):
                try:
                    f= func(obj) 
                except Exception as e:
                    pass
                else:
                    if f is None:
                        pass
                    else:
                        f = f, a, b

                return f
            return new_func
        return f1
```

This is applied to function like this

```
@mydecorator('test1', 'test2')
def getdata():
   pass
```

My thinking was that  decorator takes function name as argument but here

i am not able to get from where did `func` came and `obj` came

Comment: It doesn't look like this particular decorator would even work - I get errors when attempting it locally.  Are you sure this is what you're seeing?

Comment: @Makoto i removed some bits because of some privacy ,  but its similar to that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This -

```
@mydecorator('test1', 'test2')
def getdata():
   pass
```

is similar to (without the `decofunc` name ever being created) -

```
decofunc = mydecorator('test1', 'test2')
@decofunc
def getdata():
   pass
```

Since `mydecorator()` returns `f1` , which accepts the function as the argument.

Then it gets the `getdata` function as argument. and returns the `new_func` , and the name `getdata` is replaced with this `new_func` , hence whenever you call `getdata()` it calls this `new_func` function, which internally calls your original `getdata()` function.

Comment: thanks for explanantion . what will be the argument to `new_func`  i mean what will be `obj`

Comment: obj would be what you pass to getdata at runtime when you call it .